# Why does Python's time.time() return a wrong result?

Tags: python, windows, time, windows-8.1, timing

I'm not asking about the difference between `time.time()` and `time.clock()`, I'm asking why the result returned is flat out wrong.

It says that 37 seconds have passed when it's really been about 5 seconds... Is this a problem with my OS clock? My python install? I've searched around but can't find anyone with the same issue.

And here's my code:

```
t0 = time.time()
weightMatrix.MultiprocessMatrix(sigmaI, sigmaX)
t1 = time.time() - t0
print('Parallel took {} seconds'.format(t1))

t0 = time.time()
weightMatrix.CreateMatrix(sigmaI, sigmaX)
t2 = time.time() - t0
print('Serial took {} seconds'.format(t2))
print('Parallel time was {}% faster than serial time!'.format((t2/t1)*100))
```

The second one, `t2` sees to be accurate, but the first reports a much larger numer than it should.

Edit2: I was just thinking, `time.time()` is said to measure just clock time. But `time.clock()` measures processor time. I am using `time()`, so this shoudlnt be an issue, but... I am trying to compare a serial approach and a parallel approach to a function. If one if running many processes in serial, it would actually measure much more processing time than with one core? But again, that shouldn't matter using `time()`. I have no idea, since the second one (the serial fucntion) seems to measure time correctly.

Comment: what os do you use? ( I think time.time and time.clock are os-dependent)

Comment: Difficult to usefully comment on code you haven't shown.

Comment: could also be a latency issue

Comment: @NightShadeQueen windows 8.1

Comment: You may be experiencing the [Microsoft Minute](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/99mar/19990318.html).

Comment: Perhaps this is due to lazy evaluation of t0, t1, and t2? Python doesn't need to know their values until the print statements evaluate their arguments, so it's possible that their values are determined much later than you expect.

Comment: I am facing this very issue on an Ubuntu 18.04. Did you figure out something?

Comment: @LucaCappelletti Sorry, I don't recall if I ever did. Long time ago!

Answer (score -1):

According to the help documents, time.clock():

> Help on built-in function clock in module time:
>
> clock(...)
>       clock() -> floating point number
>
> ```
> Return the CPU time or real time since the start of the process or since
> the first call to clock().  This has as much precision as the system
> records.
> ```

So I don't know what you're trying to do without code, but my guess is it's related to what time.clock() is doing vs. what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just trying to time two seperate functions to compare. See my edited post